# MYSQL combining results into single item for display

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently having an issue where I run a query on multiple tables getting the results, but they are all being considered independent. I've tried a couple ways of combining them, but because my SQL knowledge is limited I can't seem to get what I want to happen.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t.*, s.quantity, s.rrp, ts.thumbnail, ts.bigpic, t.rating 
                FROM tyres t 
                INNER JOIN stocklevels s 
                ON t.stockcode = s.stockcode 
                LEFT JOIN tyre_treads ts    
                ON t.treadid = ts.recid 
                LEFT JOIN reseller r 
                ON s.city=r.recid 
                WHERE s.quantity> 0 AND s.rrp > 0
```

I've tried adding GROUP BY t.recid and a couple other basic solutions but this doesn't seem to work. I've added a couple images which might help.

[image]

As you can see the bottom Toyo tyres are the same, just with varying cities and quantities.

Here they are on the website.

[image]

I'm wanting to combine they so that they say minimum 6 in stock and shows only once on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is at least one column in your SQK resukt, which contains different values  (like city in your example for "the same" tire, group by won't work. You must adapt your SQL statement in a way, that it only picks columns with the same values. Especially, you should remove the `t.*` from your sql and name all columns (You then will not need the distinct anymore). 
Then, you sum over quantity to get the combined value for this column as wanted.

```
SELECT r.recid, sum(s.quantity), s.rrp, ts.thumbnail, ts.bigpic, t.rating 
            FROM tyres t 
            INNER JOIN stocklevels s 
            ON t.stockcode = s.stockcode 
            LEFT JOIN tyre_treads ts    
            ON t.treadid = ts.recid 
            LEFT JOIN reseller r 
            ON s.city=r.recid 
            WHERE s.quantity> 0 AND s.rrp > 0
            GROUP BY recid
```

Comment: Thankyou this seemed to work, my only problem is the quantity no longer displays, how can I pull the summed value?